# Is it wrong to put ID's on DOM elements for automation because it would turn their CSS classes into singletons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, automation

I'm wondering what the correct way to go about Automation (like Selenium) is. I was told that I shouldn't put ID's on elements, because this can lead to JS errors (if duplicate ID's exists) and can cause an elements CSS classes to become singletons. I would agree with this, but not having IDs can make Automation a pain in the rear.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got some pretty bad advice.

The "id" and "class" namespaces are distinct. Give page elements (**unique**) "id" values when you need to find them efficiently and reliably.

(What you mean by "Automation", by the way, is not entirely clear.)

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I edited my post. In my case I am specifically using Selenium.

Comment: Also, be aware that IE creates a global variable for each id on the page. So IDs have to be unique not only with each other but also with global variables in javascript.

Comment: Is it a bad idea than to create global variables in javascript either by instantiating them (e.g. foo = new Object()) or by giving id's to DOM elements? It seems like this would make your javascript classes singletons.

Comment: It's best to avoid global variables for a **lot** of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

you should still use ID's for unique identification JS-wise, but should style for your classes CSS-wise

```
<DIV id='DIV1' class='basicDiv' />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better rule of thumb is to be careful when putting IDs on elements.  This is true for virtually all languages, the problem with non-compiled languages is that depending on your editing environment this won't be discovered until run-time.  The browser will not complain about HTML elements with duplicate IDs until you try to reference it in JavaScript.

IDs are very useful in unique identifying sections of your HTML, but are used differently than classes.  Usually, classes are used to style elements that share common properties while IDs are used to uniquely identify a specific element for processing.